# Always getting wrong time difference using Moment

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I have end date time in UTC format and with that time I am doing comparing it with current time on my server. I want to check that time difference should be 5 minutes. But I am always getting huge time difference.

```
 console.log('utc format... ', currentDate, slot.endTimeWithDuration);
 // log -> utc format...  moment("2019-11-30T10:16:00.002") 2019-11-30T16:40:00Z
console.log('diff.... ', moment(slot.endTimeWithDuration).diff(currentDate,'minutes'))
 // diff....  383
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The difference is ~six hours and 23 minutes, those times appear ~23 minutes apart, so I guess you're in a timezone six hours from UTC?

Comment: yes, @jonrsharpe, that is server time which is 6 hours delay..

Answer (score 0):

Try this something like :

```
moment.utc(moment(endTime, "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(startTime, "HH:mm:ss"))).format("mm")
```

Or You can also make it more simple like below example:

```
var startTime = moment("07:27:28 am", 'hh:mm:ss a');
var endTime = moment("08:24:59 pm", 'hh:mm:ss a');

endTime.diff(startTime, 'hours');
```

Comment: thank you @jatin.7744, for your answer.. I was already getting diff() value but my server time is 6 hours delay.. So what should I do? How to get rid of this server time issue?

Comment: @JaynaTanawala Can you please me which server you are using ?